# reinterpret_cast<unsigned long> Invalid Cast

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am working with a Hashtable in C++. The hash function:

```
// Default hash function class
template <typename K>
struct KeyHash {
    unsigned long operator()(const K& key) const {
        return reinterpret_cast<unsigned long>(key) % TABLE_SIZE;
    }
};
```

Then when I declared hashtable as:

```
HashTable<int, std::string> hmap;
```

Its showing:

> Invalid cast from 'int' type to 'unsigned_long_int'

Whats the problem with `reinterpret_cast<unsigned long>` here?

Comment: Maybe it's that `sizeof(unsigned long) != sizeof(int)`, so "reinterpreting the bit pattern" may not make sense... I'm not sure though.

Comment: Who the **** give that downvote? Everyone in SO don't know everything like you.

Comment: It seems you are assuming I gave you that downvote. I didn't. [Proof](http://imgur.com/2tey48m).

Comment: Nop. I didn't mean you :) Really people in SO nowadays become so tough!

Comment: Downvotes happen. Complaining about them is usually a waste of time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't `reinterpret_cast` between two integer types, period. That's not what `reinterpret_cast` is for. If you want to cast between two integer types, use `static_cast`.

If your goal is to really "reinterpret the bit pattern" then you'll have to cast to *reference*. That is, `reinterpret_cast<unsigned long&>(x)` is valid if `x` is an lvalue of type `int`. But now you are getting into dangerous territory, as this is in general undefined behaviour, and will probably work on a 32-bit x86 platform but will do something bad on a 64-bit x86 platform where `unsigned long` is longer than `int`.

Comment: +1 and AC for a good answer and not for down-voting me (people do without reason) :)

Comment: Accessing the value of `reinterpret_cast<unsigned long&>(x)` is _always_ UB; the cast is only syntactically valid.

Comment: It's always UB, but it's still possible that it behaves predictably on some implementations, just as with all UB.

Answer (score 3):

According to the C++ Standard (5.2.10 Reinterpret cast)

> 2 The reinterpret_cast operator shall not cast away constness
>   (5.2.11). **An expression of integral, enumeration, pointer, or
>   pointer-to-member type can be explicitly converted to its own type;
>   such a cast yields the value of its operand.**

Use `static_cast` instead.

Comment: +1 but the other guy is already got accepted, Sir :)